# Where is Apple's latest AudioUnit Example code

Tags: ios, macos, core-audio

I am writing a MacOS Audio Unit Extension. When I google for the example code I get only an out-of-date page on Apple's site, stating "Important: This document is no longer being updated.". The version of the code there is V2.5

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/AudioUnitV3Example/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016185-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

I also found on github, Version 3.0 of the same example code...

https://github.com/Lax/iOS-Swift-Demos/tree/master/AudioUnitV3Example

I strongly prefer to use the latest code, but I can't be confident this code from a 3rd party is genuine or if it's the absolute latest version. I would expect Apple to provide the definitive example code.

Where or how do I obtain the latest Audio Unit example code from Apple?

Comment: It seems that Apple reverted back to v2.5 for one reason or another. You can verify this by looking at the Internet Archive's Way Back Machine. https://web.archive.org/web/20180130164313/https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AudioUnitV3Example/Introduction/Intro.html
I spot checked the version 3.0 I downloaded from Apple long ago with the one on GitHub and it looks to be the same.